# Как скрыть пользователей с формы входа в Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, users

Создал пользователей для расшаривания папок. Суть в том, что я расшариваю группу папок определенному пользователю - даю человеку логин и пароль и он может заходить на мой компьютер и получать доступ к этим папкам.

Хочу, чтобы такие пользователи (учетные записи) системы не были видны на форме входа, потому что с моего компьютера они никогда заходить не будут. Куда копать? Где отключать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создать ветку

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList
```

создать параметр `DWORLD` с именем пользователя для скрытия со значением 0, пользователь скрыт.

Comment: Спасибо огромное.